# Can not find symbol in setting object

Tags: java

When compiling, the error comes out. And I am so confused. Any help is appreciated!

```
Error mesage is:src\com\example\Testerx.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setDog(foo.Dog)
location: class foo.Employee
p.setDog(dog);
```

`Employee` class:

```
package foo;

public class Employee {
    public Employee() {}

    String name = "";

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    String empID = "1122";

    public void setEmpID(String empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    public String getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }

    Dog dog = null;

    public Dog getDog() {
        return dog;
    }

    public void setDog(Dog dog) {
        this.dog = dog;
    }
}
```

`Testerx` class:

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Testerx extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  IOException, ServletException {
        String name = request.getParameter("userName");
        // request.setAttribute("name",name);
        foo.Employee p = new foo.Employee();
        p.setName("Evan");
        foo.Dog dog = new foo.Dog();
        dog.setName("Spike");
        p.setDog(dog);
        request.setAttribute("person", p);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/result4.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

`Dog` class:

```
package foo;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Dog {
    private String name = "";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: We are not magicians. Post your code please.

Comment: I don't think your `p` (whatever that is) has a `setDog` method...

Comment: `p` seems to be an `Employee`.

Comment: It said your post are most likely the code! I cannot put code there

Comment: When you do not Show the code, we can't help you. Post `Employee` and `Testerx` class.

Comment: @andytang try adding some more detail about your problem then?

Comment: in p  Dog dog = null;
   public Dog getDog() {
        return dog;
    }
 public void setDog(Dog dog){
 this.dog=dog;

Comment: Do you conform to the "Obfuscation" school of code formatting? Please format your code to comply with Java guidelines, or at least be consistent.

Comment: Your code works for me. Try to clean your project cache (if you're using an IDE) and rebuild your project.

Comment: Finally the answer is found in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html. The compiling command line I used is "javac -d classes src\com\example\\*", and it always has problem described as above.
Later, after I change it to "javac -sourcepath src -d classes src\com\example\\*", the problem is solved.